# How to get Predecessor and Successor in a directed graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

I am trying to get Predecessor and Successor of a vertex from a directed graph implemented with adjacency list.

here s a brief description of my class :

```
template <class T>
class Digraph
{
public:
    Digraph();
    ~Digraph();

void predecessor(T u);
void successor(T u, T v);


private:
    std::map<T, std::set<T>> graphe;
}
```

Here is what I tried :

```
template <class T>
const std::set<T> Digraph<T>::predecessor(T u) const
{
    std::set<T> p;

    int index = 0;
    for (auto it = graphe.begin(); it != graphe.end(); ++it, index++)
    {
        for(T el : *it) //I got the error here
        {
            if (el == u)
                p.insert(index);
        }
    }
    return p;
}

template <class T>
const std::set<T> Digraph<T>::successor(T u) const
{
    return graphe.at(u);
}
```

I get the error in the inner loop.
Does anyone have an idea for an implementation? or can help me by telling me what i forgot.

Comment: Firstly, there is no variable named `graphe`. I assume you meant the member variable `graph`. Iterators to a `std::map` will derefernce to a _pair_, where the first element is the key and the second element is the value. If you read the compiler's error message carefully (which by the way, you should have included with your question), you will see that you're trying to run a range-based loop on a pair. What you meant was `for (T el : it->second)`

Comment: Note that for predecessor, you would surely want `p.insert(it->first)`. Using `index` to count nodes is totally bogus in the general case, unless you can guarantee that the graph _always_ contains nodes numbered sequentially from zero with no gaps.

Comment: @paddy you re right, i missed the e at the end, I edited my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching through the entire graph to find predecessors is a possibly costly operation. You would make your life much easier if you just stored all back-edges in a separate, identical structure:

```
std::map<T, std::set<T>> inverted;
```

Then, your member functions would be quite trivial:

```
template <typename T>
std::set<T> const& Digraph<T>::successor(T const& v) const {
    return graph.at(v);
}
template <typename T>
std::set<T> const& Digraph<T>::predecessor(T const& u) const {
    return inverted.at(u);
}
```

Note that the return type is an `std::set<T> const&` instead of an `std::set<T>`. This means that you don't copy the entire set.

For insertion the code becomes:

```
graph[v].insert(u);
inverted[u].insert(v); // new line
```

---

However, if you really want to keep your expensive lookup, maybe because it happens really seldom you can do it like this:

```
template <class T>
std::set<T> Digraph<T>::predecessor(T const& u) const {
    std::set<T> p;

    for (auto const& [v, set]: graph)
        for(auto const& w : set)
            if (u == w) {
                p.insert(v);
                break;
            }

    return p;
}
```

Please note however, that this will create **copies** of the values stored in your graph. If you only have integers, that's no issue. But if you have class-objects in there, copying might not be what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was so helpful !